# Nullable dateTime without losing methods

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I've made a method to convert a datetime object to a date-only format. In order to access it, I have to assign the value of my parameter to the value that will be in a datatable. The obvious method would thus be to add a `?` after the DateTime object to make it nullable, however this removes it's methods (or at least, the one I need to use), making my method worthless.

```
string dateWithOutTime(DateTime? datetime)
{
    string reply = datetime.Date.ToString();
    return reply;
}
```

usage:

```
string str = dateWithOutTime(*DataSet*.*DataTable[n]*.Rows[n][n] as DateTime?);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without adding any extra objects?

*Note: a star (`*`) denotes a variable type/object*

Comment: What does the `*DataSet*.*DataTable[n]*.Rows[n][n]` have to do with the nullable date? I fail to see the connection, and your actual problem. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Maarten The content in that cell is in a DateTime format, however the compiler doesn't know this. I assumed it would thus be similar to a var, ergo my usage of `as`.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime?` doesn't have the same methods as `DateTime`, they're different types. You have to retrieve the actual datetime value using `DateTime?`'s `Value` property:

```
string dateWithOutTime(DateTime? datetime)
{
    if(datetime.HasValue)
        return datetime.Value.Date.ToString();
    else
        return //...

}
```

Read the documentation for `Nullable<T>` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This appears to have partially worked. I still have the time element of the object, does `Value` affect this?

Comment: @Wolfish Not at all, `Value` retrieves the underlying `DateTime` object, same as if you had casted the db value to `DateTime` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your problem, I'd say you need to check if your DateTime? parameter is null or not. If it is, return an empty string (or a string you want to display for missing dates). If it isn't, you can use the `Value` property:

```
string dateWithOutTime(DateTime? datetime)
{
    return datetime.HasValue ? datetime.Value.Date.ToString() : String.Empty;
}
```

### Update

If you only want the date-part in your string and you want it to be culture-sensitive, you can use `ToShortDateString()` instead of `ToString()`. You can even leave out the `Date` property:

```
string dateWithOutTime(DateTime? datetime)
{
    return datetime.HasValue
        ? datetime.Value.ToShortDateString()
        : String.Empty;
}
```